# Firefox displaying HTML page as code

Tags: html, firefox

I am following a tutorial for developing a simple Facebook app, yet the sample code will not work in Firefox (works fine in IE) - it literlly just displays the code, all on one line.

Full code is here, if it is helpful - http://pastebin.com/YggfCQEH

Can anybody tell me why this is not working? I've no doubt that this is something really simple, but I cannot spot what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This could be solved a lot quicker and easier if we can have the link to the page.

Comment: I'm developing internally, so no can do I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the encoding was UTF-8, and apparently Firefox does not like that. Changing the encoding to ANSI sorted the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your server returns mime/type `text/plain`. What is the filename? Chances are, if it's not `.html` or `.htm` that is the problem.

Comment: The server could also be returning `text/plain` even if it's `.html`. Best way to debug would be to check the headers returned by the page in question.

Comment: I've tried both .html and .php. This is running on a server that has been up for a while. @bfrohs - when you say check the headers, what do you mean? If it's just the page source, then that is showing correctly.

Comment: Page Info in FF is telling me - Type: text/html, Encoding: UTF-8 and Render mode: Quirks mode.

Comment: @DavidGard, you're checking the code Facebook is fetching, not the app on Facebook, correct?

Comment: Sure, checking the headers is a better way, the suffix thingie was just a shortcut.

Comment: Ok, sorted - I changed the encoding to ANSI and it is now working! Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to find some other working page on that server, and check what is the files extension that generates correctly, and rename your file with the same extension as that.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox has an option in the View menu you may check. View>Page Style, if No Style is selected FF will disable all CSS and leave you with just html, that's my first guess. (I only suggest this since you say its only FF and this solved a friend's problem just the other day...)

Your code looks fine, but there could be something in the js file screwing it up... i'd double check functions.js for anything weird.

Comment: It's not that a style isn't being dsiplayed, it is that the page is being displayed as code. And functions.js is currently blank, so cannot be that.